# Angular 12 not binding to values from webapi: returns NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs6, angular12

I've been unable to bind to a webapi call in Angular12/Typescript.

The browser displays this error:
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Data is successfully being returned from the api call. I'm not sure what I'm missing here?

**Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-system-of-record-search', 
  templateUrl: './system-of-record-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./system-of-record-search.component.scss']

})
export class SystemOfRecordSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  model?: SystemOfRecord[];

  constructor(
    private configApi: ConfigApi
  ) { }
  ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.configApi.searchSystemOfRecord().subscribe(
      (data: SystemOfRecord[]) => {
        this.model = data;
      }
    );
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div *ngIf="model">
        <select id="selSystemOfRecord" class="form-control">
            <option *ngFor="let item of model" [ngValue]="item.systemOfRecordId">{{item.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>  
</div>
```

**Api Provider**:

```
  searchSystemOfRecord(): Observable<SystemOfRecord[]> {
    const url = `${this.domain}/api/systemofrecord/search`;
    return this.http.post<SystemOfRecord[]>(url, {}, { responseType: 'json' });
  }
```

Comment: Apparently the data you are getting is not iterable, like the error suggest. My guess is that you are receiving an object. Have you actually looked at what data you are getting before asking? So what ARE you getting as a response?

Comment: Hi. Can you shared a response example of your api?

Comment: This is the response.  It appears to be the Observable...but I expected (and it's typed) as just an array. Thanks!
```
Object { systemOfRecords: (22) […] }
​
systemOfRecords: Array(2) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
​​
0: Object { systemOfRecordId: 8, name: "dsdf", statusId: 1, … }
​​
1: Object { systemOfRecordId: 9, name: "dsdf", statusId: 1, … }
​​
length: 2​​
<prototype>: Array []
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
consoleProvider.ts:12:42
```

Comment: Try to set this instead:
 this.model = data?.systemOfRecords ?? []

Looks like you are getting an object, this will set it to the key with an array inside, or an empty list if it's null.

Comment: Thank you. you're response along with changing the type of the subscribe to accurately reflects what's being returned fixed this issue.